# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError:'function' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask website running on nginx and gunicorn. I can use a self made inside `__init__.py` with just `flask run` and it runs perfectly. However if I use `gunicorn flaskapp:app` it hits me with the error

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'printcarousel is undefined'

Declaring the function inside **init**.py with

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(printcarousel=printcarousel)
```

With the function itself being

```
def printcarousel(recipeid, active=""):
    return "something"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I got a fix to it.
Instead of making the functions in the **init**.py file move them to the main python file using  the `app.context_processor` in this website.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/

Answer (score -1):

had a similar problem, and wondering if anyone could give me an example applying that, I have to ".py" files, one imports the other and the ".html" refers to the ".py" that intersects with both as:

"pyWithUSDfunction.py"->"pythatimportandrenderHTML.py"->"pageWith{{usd(value)}}.html

the HTML file reports:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'usd' is undefined
```

Comment: If you face a similar problem you can leave a comment of the original question or create a new question focused on your problem. Answers should try to solve the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29890651)